# Workspace & Versioning - Can't be able to publish contents

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I am using typo3 version 4.7.12 and have an issue with workspace "Ready to publish" stage. 
I've an editor and he is added contents through a "draft-workspace". I was able to publish 99% of the work done, but there are few pages remaining. 
In that pages, I've 5 contents to be publish. These contents are now in "Ready to publish" stage. But I can't able to publish that contents.
When I add new contents it can be able to push the stage from "Editing" -> "Ready to publish" -> "Publish".

But in that 5 existing content elements, I can push from "Editing" -> "Ready to publish" only. 
When I try to publish these contents, no process is going on and all these 5 have no state change.

Anybody know why its happened ? Is it a mistake of that content element or any change in the Database ? Please help me,

Thanks & Regards,

Arun C

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something went wrong and you will need to delete the ghost entries from the database. Make sure to create a backup beforehand.
Such things should not happen, but unless you want to take a journey into the strange mysteries of the TYPO3 CMS workspace implementation, you should just delete those entries and move on.